# Cannot clear custom control in OnPaint method

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I have a custom control that's function is to display an image created by a external library. I have implemented this by overloading the OnPaint function, generating and drawing the image there.

My issue is that when the size of my control changes and the image is recreated and drawn the old image is still visible.

My OnPaint method is relatively simple since the image creation is in it's own method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    if (image == null || this.Width != image.Width || this.Height != image.Height)
    {
        // Remove the old image so we don't accidentally draw it later.
        this.image = null;

        // Attempt to clear the control.
        //e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

        try
        {
            this.Plot(); // Create my image from the library based on current size.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(ex.Message, this.Font);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ex.Message, this.Font, Brushes.Black, (this.Width - size.Width) / 2, (this.Height - size.Height) / 2);
        }
    }
    if (this.image != null)
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(image, 0, 0);
}
```

As you can see I've tried a couple of things to clear the control including the Graphics.Clear method and redrawing the background myself. None of which have had any effect.

What can I do to clear my control before I redraw it?

Comment: Does it work to call this.invalidate before drawing?

Comment: Well I was trying to avoid calling it in OnPaint since as I understand it invalidating causes a repaint so I thought that would create an infinite loop. adv12's suggestion to invalidate on resize not only gets around that but solves the issue (It's still too soon for me to accept an answer)

Comment: You're right... haven't worked on winforms in a while, but adv12's answer is nice. :]

Comment: Move your FillRectangle call before your if condition.  In your control's constructor, set ResizeRedraw = true and DoubleBuffered = true.

Comment: It is the job of OnPaintBackground() to ensure you paint on top of a "clean" background.  The default one you inherit uses the BackColor property to fill the control.  Pretty unclear what happened to it.  ResizeRedraw is required if you inherit from a container control, like Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that only part of your control is being invalidated, so only part of it is getting repainted.  To fix this, add a `Resize` event handler and call `Invalidate()` in there to invalidate the entire control and force a full repaint.

Edit: In the comments on the question, @LarsTech recommends setting `ResizeRedraw`, which I had never noticed before.  That seems cleaner and more in keeping with the design of the library than the `Resize` event handler I've suggested.